# Multiple functions in Angular config

Tags: angularjs, config

I'm working on my first Angular project and currently stuck (again).

My problem is I have two functions that needs to implement in the Angular config.

- For Facebook connect (I use [ngFacebook](https://github.com/GoDisco/ngFacebook))
- For routing ( I use [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router))

What I cannot understand is, both of there modules using `<angular module>.config`, I don't know how to combine these two , because when I read the Angular docs it seems like [it gets a name, and a function](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module).

Following is my current code (and these two works individually)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/state1");
        $stateProvider
          .state('state1',{
            url: 'state1',
            templateUrl: "../pages/form.html"
          });
          $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
    });



myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['facebook'])

    .config([
        'FacebookProvider',
        function(FacebookProvider) {
            var myAppId = '<FB app id>';
            FacebookProvider.init(myAppId);}

    ]
)
```

How can I combine these two functions in to one

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['facebook','ui.router']).config(
     facebook functon and ui-route function
 )
```

I have found almost the same [SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24659505/multiple-config-blocks-in-angular-module) but unfortunately no answer.

Comment: Upvote for "`currently stuck (again)`". Lolx - [here's how it looks, even 6 years after your question](https://miro.medium.com/max/545/0*Le4NWnMPwFOvu5ea.png)  :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router','facebook'])
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, FacebookProvider){
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/state1");
        $stateProvider
          .state('state1',{
            url: 'state1',
            templateUrl: "../pages/form.html"
          });
          $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);

        var myAppId = '<FB app id>';
            FacebookProvider.init(myAppId);
    });
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks a lot.... I was trying to fix this for last 2 days :)... thanks again... all I had to modify is to add `$locationProvider` in the same line with `$stateProvider` :)

Comment: @words Like Jared: Hellom I have a similar problem. We have several routing and a othersise condition. Waht can I do? what is the trick?$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);

Comment: @AliSaberi If you're still having the issue ask it ask a question and myself or someone else will answer.

Comment: thanks. I opened a new question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33971500/multiple-configuration-in-angularjs-module?noredirect=1#comment55699499_33971500

Answer (score 31):

Alternatively, you can chain configs to keep things isolated like so

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router','facebook'])
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
       ... state provider config ...
    })
    .config(function(FacebookProvider){
       ... facebook provider config ...
    });
```

or you could split them right up like so

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router','facebook']);

myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
  ...
});

myApp.config(function(FacebookProvider){
  ...
});
```

Comment: I prefer this solution because you could separate the logic out into multiple files.

Comment: yes, keeping the logic in separate files feels 'cleaner' to me as it keeps concerns distinct facebook config separate to state provider config