# multiple configuration in AngularJS module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute, angular-translate

I am using ng-route and ng-translate at the same time, where both require configuration in the module. Apparentely my routing is working but my ng-translate is haveing problems of being in the same confing with routing configuration.

```
"use strict";
(function(){
var app = angular.module('ratingApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngMessages', 'ngFileUpload', 'ngAnimate', 'pascalprecht.translate']);
app.config(function($routeProvider, $translateProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/list.html',
            controller: 'candidatescontroller'
            })
        .when('/candidate/:candiateIndex', {
            templateUrl: 'views/candiate.html',
            controller: 'candidatecontroller'
            })
    // .when('', )
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/'});
    $translateProvider.translations('en', {
        'TOPIC':'Candidate Poll'
            });
    $translateProvider.translations('fr', {
        'TOPIC':'Poll de Candidate'
            });
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en'); 

});
}());
```

Here is the error that I get:

> [Unknown provider:  $translateProvider <-  $translate <-andidatescontroller](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=%20$translateProvider%20%3C-%20%20$translate%20%3C-andidatescontroller)

BTW: here is the end of my index.html in the term of inclduing requirements

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/angular-translate.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="js/vendor/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/ng-file-upload-shim.min.js"></script> <!-- for no html5 browsers support -->
    <script src="js/vendor/ng-file-upload.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/vendor/angular-animate.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="js/rateApp.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services/candidates.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/services/modal.js"></script>       
    <script src="js/candidatescontroller.js"></script>
    <script src="js/candidecontroller.js"></script>
```

Controller codes related to ng-tranlate:

```
use strict";
(function(){
var candidatescontroller = function($scope, $http, candidatesFactory, $timeout, modalService, $location, $anchorScroll, $translate){
    $scope.changeLanguage = function (key) {
            $translate.use(key);
    };
candidatescontroller.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', 'candidatesFactory', '$timeout', 'modalService', '$location', '$anchorScroll', ' $translate'];
angular.module('ratingApp').controller('candidatescontroller', candidatescontroller);
}());
```

I am following [ng-newsletter](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/angular-translate.html) article, and it worked for me when I used it in another app without routing,

Also, my routing was working before adding this ng-translate configurations to the module.

A live demo of my code can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7jFrXj0v0CL8A3Byhyyy?p=preview)

Comment: Have you included the reference ?

Comment: yes my friend, It's under angular.min.js and above my app
        <script src="js/vendor/angular-translate.min.js"></script>

Comment: can you create a plunker code or jsfiddle?

Comment: sure. yes, let me minimize the project and put the minimume there.

Comment: Post the code for this controller.

Comment: @dfsq: I updated the post in the term of contoller.

Comment: @Sajeetharan plunker code is here:http://plnkr.co/edit/7jFrXj0v0CL8A3Byhyyy?p=preview

Comment: @dfsq plunker codes is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/7jFrXj0v0CL8A3Byhyyy?p=preview

Comment: I don't see the same error on your plunker, some of the references are not loading

Comment: @Sajeetharan the only difference is I removed the path in front of refrences since I cant make directories there., and the whole codes are pasted the files.

Comment: @Sajeetharan See the route is working but {{ 'TOPIC' | translate }} which ng-traslate is not working

Comment: @AliSaberi Save your plunkr code, so other people can see your changes.

Comment: @BabajideFowotade DONE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a space in `$translate`

```
candidatescontroller.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', 'candidatesFactory', '$timeout', 'modalService', '$location', '$anchorScroll', ' $translate'];
```

remove it

```
candidatescontroller.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', 'candidatesFactory', '$timeout', 'modalService', '$location', '$anchorScroll', '$translate'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your candidatecontroller.js file at the bottom, you have a space injected with '$translate', remove the space

```
candidatescontroller.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', 'candidatesFactory', '$timeout', 'modalService', '$location', '$anchorScroll', '$translate'];
angular.module('ratingApp').controller('candidatescontroller', candidatescontroller);
```